# Text color breaks CSS transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, font-awesome, bulma

I cannot figure out why this breaks it. I have an a element which uses CSS transitions to fade into a gradient background on hover. For whatever reason whenever I set the text color on hover to white the transition breaks?

```css
.social-item {
    margin-left: 0.25vw;
    padding: 0.1vw;
    transition: 0.2s;
    color: white;
}
.social-item:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #8E2DE2, #DC0486);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" class="social-item"><i class="fab fa-keybase"></i> Keybase</a>
```

I'm also using Bulma and Font Awesome.

Comment: not entirely clear what you want. give more clarification, please. and why are you dublicate `color: white` in hover? this rule is already in the class `social-item`

Answer (score 0):

What I figured your problem to be is that you're trying to do gradient transition. It is not supported. But if you want to simulate it, you can use the opacity property in css. Add opacity: 0 to the main element (.social-item) and opacity: 1 to the hover state (.social-events:hover). Hence the transition: 0.2 will apply on the opacity, as it is supported, thus simulating the desired outcome.
Thus the final css, shall be.

```
.social-item {
    margin-left: 0.25vw;
    padding: 0.1vw;
    transition: 0.2s;
    color: white;
    opacity:0;
}
.social-item:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #8E2DE2, #DC0486);
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

If you actually want to have the thing display normally, and not just on hover, then opacity: 0 wont work for you. You have to use the pseudo-selector :after to add a dummy element to the main class and work all the transitions and background gradient stuff on that. Here is a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/adil-bub/pen/yLOBzEv).

Comment: @Sean Okay. So I finally figured out a more legitimate way for you to actually simulate a background transition. Since it is a gradient we had to do all of this, if it were just some color, your way would have worked just fine. Anyway, here is a working [codepen link] (https://codepen.io/adil-bub/pen/yLOBzEv)

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply make transitions with background gradients.
[Animatable CSS Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)
Use pseudo-element and do an opacity transform.

```css
.social-item {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.social-item::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #8e2de2, #dc0486);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

.social-item:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" class="social-item"><i class="fab fa-keybase"></i> Keybase</a>
```

A nice [article](https://keithjgrant.com/posts/2017/07/transitioning-gradients/) about this.
Thank you!